# Issue with IF statement in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a slight issue with this statement. I'm using the CodeIgniter Framework and it seems to bring back 3 and 5 everytime but I can't figure out why.

$row->gType has a different value each time
$row2->tcID just links to gType and I'm grabbing the map and type.

```
<?
        foreach ($stats as $row){ 
            foreach ($gametypes as $row2){
                if($row2->tcID = $row->gType){
                    $map = $row2->mName;
                    $type = $row2->gtName;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

$row->gType goes through the values 2 and 1 in this circumstance. I echoed values in the script to check.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Use `==` for a comparison: `if($row2->tcID == $row->gType)`

Comment: Ohh dear. Rather stupid of me. Cheers!

Comment: I think we all have done that mistake once ;)

Comment: You are free to post the solution as an answer if you think others will benefit from it, or delete the question altogether. Leaving it around as unanswered is just causing clutter.

Comment: I'll post the updated solution tomorrow. Have to wait 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was a silly mistake. Probably just reading over it too quickly. Comparison in the IF statement was incorrect.

```
<?
        foreach ($stats as $row){ 
            foreach ($gametypes as $row2){
                if($row2->tcID == $row->gType){
                    $map = $row2->mName;
                    $type = $row2->gtName;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: choose your answer as corret =)

Comment: I need to wait a few hours still ;)